# Binding Height from code behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I have a custom GridView like control made of a Grid panel with several controls in each row (All of them from System.Windows.Controls).

The user requested that the row Height will grow unrestricted with the control's content. I'm having a problem to maintain the size of all the controls in each row with relation to the highest one.

I'm trying to one-way bind the Height of all the controls in each row to the RowDefenition ActualHeight property. but it is not working as I expect it to work (Each control keeps it's own size to the minimum)

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Here is the code where I'm trying to bind:

```
                RowDefinition rowDef = new RowDefinition();

                cellsGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef);
                rowDef.Name = "gvRow" + cellsGrid.RowDefinitions.Count;

                cellsGrid.Children.Add(controlToAdd);
                Grid.SetRow(controlToAdd, rowIndex);
                Grid.SetColumn(controlToAdd, columnIndex);

                Binding bindH = new Binding("ActualHeight");
                bindH.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
                bindH.Source = rowDef;
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(controlToAdd,RowDefinition.HeightProperty, bindH);

                controlToAdd.TabIndex = (totalTabIndex + 1); totalTabIndex++;
                cell.CellElement = controlToAdd;
                cell.EndEdit += new GridViewCell.GridViewEditHandler(cell_EndEdit);
```

Comment: Try setting your Control's `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch`, so it expands to fill all available space. Also, I don't think `RowDefinition` has an `ActualHeight` property, to the binding is probably evaluating to nothing. You'd need to bind to the `ActualHeight` of your control, however that value isn't know until after it's been Rendered. I suppose you could use `Dispatcher.Invoke` to run something after the controls have been rendered, figure out which is the tallest control in the row, and set all item to be that height.

Comment: Thank you very much, so now I'm binding the controls height only once the grid has been rendered and it all works perfect.

Comment: Glad that worked :) I posted it as an answer so you can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your Control's `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch`, so it expands to fill all available space.

Also, I don't think `RowDefinition` has an `ActualHeight` property, so the binding is probably evaluating to nothing. You'd need to bind to the `ActualHeight` of your control, however that value isn't know until after it's been Rendered. I suppose you could use `Dispatcher.Invoke` to run something after the controls have been rendered, figure out which is the tallest control in the row, and set all item to be that height.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the Height binding in XAML, not in codebehind.

Use the  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" property on your control.

Alternative, use Height="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=ActualHeight} to bind with the actual height of your maingrid.

Comment: Hi De ruige, I don't think I can use XAML since the grid is being generated in run-time. is there any way I can do this from code behind?

Comment: @Esh: Might i ask just why your grid is being generated at runtime?

Comment: Isn't a StackPanel better if you want to append items?

Comment: @De ruige, because I can't tell what type of data/columns it will have to display in design time. only when the user select the data. it was probably a bad idea to not use the built-in DataGrid. but now when the project is already released I'd rather not rewrite it to use the Data Grid.

Comment: @snurre, The Grid Panel makes it much more easy to arrange the controls in a grid (with rows and columns). acutely I've started with a StackPanel and changed to the Grid panel because of that. If I will use a StackPanel, will it be easier to achieve that stretch effect that I'm after?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Class1}">
            <Grid Height="{Binding YourHeightValue}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding prop1}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding prop2}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding prop3}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: And this answers the OP ... How?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your control's height(or any property) with other control's height with C# code.
Here is the example.

```
Grid myGrid = new Grid();
ListBox myList = new ListBox(); //it could be any control 
private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     myList.DataContext = this;
     myList.SetBinding(UserControl.HeightProperty,"this.myGrid.ActualHeight");
}
```

this worked for me.